# Why can't i use regional indicator symbol letter emoji in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, emoji

When I try to use emoji like "" I get this error:

```
Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji
```

Here is my code:

```py
    @commands.command(name="warcaby", aliases=["checkers"])
    async def warcabycmd(self, ctx):
      gracz1 = ctx.author
      gracz2 = ctx.message.mentions[0]
      plansza_start = """(board)"""
      embed=discord.Embed(title=f'Grasz z {gracz2}. Ruch gracza {gracz1}!', description=plansza_start, color=ctx.author.color)
      embed.add_field(name='Instrukcje', value='Wybierz pole, a wybrać pionek, a następnie wybierz, w którą stronę idziesz!')
      msg = await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
      await msg.add_reaction(":regional_indicator_f:")
      await msg.add_reaction(":regional_indicator_g:")
      await msg.add_reaction(":regional_indicator_h:")
      await msg.add_reaction("two")
      await msg.add_reaction("three")
      await msg.add_reaction("four")
      await msg.add_reaction("five")
      await msg.add_reaction("six")
      await msg.add_reaction("seven")
      await msg.add_reaction("eight")
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can use `Win` + `.` to insert an emoji directly.

Comment: from what I see in microsoft's emoji there is no regional indicator symbol letter emoji

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use them? They aren't meant to be standalone symbols.

Comment: The only official use is to use them in pairs to encode a national flag, but not all pairs actually represent a country. For example, `:regional_indicator_u::regional_indicator_s` would be the US flag. `:regional_indicator_f::regional_indicator_g`, on the other hand, isn't defined.

Comment: I want a text to be added to the message in the form of a reaction like [here](https://prnt.sc/vaadhx) @chepner

Comment: I'm not sure that's something you *should* be doing. The regional indicators aren't just stylistic variants of uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bot sees discord emojis as unicode symbols. The bot needs the symbol, not their name. It cannot react to a message if you tell it that the emoji is `:smile:`. You need to tell it that the emoji is "", or "" in etc for the letters.

You can get these on the pc, by adding a \ in front of the emoji. Have a look at the attached screenshots.

[image]

It does however not work for the numbers. The symbols to use is: '1️⃣', '2️⃣' etc.

One idea to get the emojis is to use print and copy emojis out of the terminal.
Do a simple command like and look at the output in the terminal for the emojis you give it. what the terminal prints is what you need to use in your code.

```
@commands.command()
async def emojiprint(ctx, *, emojis):
    print(emojis)
```

Here is your code with a small change I made. I tested it seems to be working!

```
    @commands.command(name="warcaby", aliases=["checkers"])
    async def warcabycmd(self, ctx):
        gracz1 = ctx.author
        gracz2 = ctx.message.mentions[0]
        plansza_start = """(board)"""
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f'Grasz z {gracz2}. Ruch gracza {gracz1}!', description=plansza_start, color=ctx.author.color)
        embed.add_field(name='Instrukcje', value='Wybierz pole, a wybrać pionek, a następnie wybierz, w którą stronę idziesz!')
        msg = await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
        emoji_list = ['', '', '', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣', '6️⃣', '7️⃣', '8️⃣']
        for i in emoji_list:
            await msg.add_reaction(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
await msg.add_reaction(":regional_indicator_a:")
```

`:regional_indicator_a:` is the code for that emoji by discord.

[image]

Comment: But I seem to get the output.

Comment: Check this link. Might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686677/discord-py-emoji-all-servers-bot-in

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat way of getting the regional indicators dynamically:

```
    from unicodedata import lookup
    ...
    indicators = ["a", "x", "z"]
    for i in indicators:
        await message.add_reaction(lookup("REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER %s" % i))
```