# using emoji from different server, nextcord bot

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

I'm trying to get emoji's from a another server.
I creates a server object for the server, it is a constant because I want to only pull from this server.

```
for emoji in main_tuple:
       emoji_name_id =await server.fetch_emoji(emoji)
       emoji_array.append(f"<{emoji_name_id.name.lower()}:{emoji_name_id.id}>")
```

error:

> nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji

I should mention I want to display it another server, I know this is probably obvious but yeah.
main_tuple is a directionary in a database that has the emoji id and name.
the error

Also the bot is part of the server it's getting the id from.
I have looked at: [discord.py emoji all servers bot in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686677/discord-py-emoji-all-servers-bot-in)
and it does not work for me.

Comment: "I'm trying to get emoji's from a another server" - ehh what? An emoji is just a Unicode code-point. You don't need to get them from anywhere. Do you mean _custom emoji artwork_ instead?

Comment: I should of clarified this. yes, I mean a custom emoji.

Answer (score 1):

First Issue, you are making a wrong reference.
`<:Name:ID>` and not `<Name:ID>` (if you don't see it, you missed the first colon)

Another issue,

`emoji_name_id.name.lower()`

Custom emojis are to have to have 'exact' name and ID as they have, by using lower method, you would be trying to reference a wrong custom emote.
For example:

The actual emote which might have the following reference `<:ThisIsACoolEmote:ID>`, while you are appending `<:thisisacoolemote:ID>` which doesn't exist

To mitigate this, you can just append `str(emoji_name_id)` which will automatically give you the correct emote reference which is in the format `<:Name:ID:>` and yes, it also will format animated emojis too, i.e:`<a:Name:ID>`

also `fetching` here might not be the best practice, you can use `bot.get_emoji` instead which gets emote from internal cache if you have access to `member` Privileged Intent.